# Converting object to string

Tags: c#

Here's the content of my object:

```
-       tree    {ItemTree}  ItemTree
        id  "0" string
        im0 null    string
    -       item    Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.List<ItemTree>
    -       [0] {ItemTree}  ItemTree
            id  "F_1"   string
            im0 "something.gif" string
    +       item    Count = 16  System.Collections.Generic.List<ItemTree>
                 parentId   "0" string
                 text   "someName"  string
  +                  Raw View       
                 parentId   null    string
                 text   ""  string
```

And I build it dynamically, so it's bigger.

It is an object from this class:

```
public class ItemTree
{
    public String id { get; set; }

    public String text { get; set; }

    public List<ItemTree> item { get; set; }

    public string im0 { get; set; }

    public String parentId { get; set; }
}
```

So, the class ItemTree has a property which itself is a List of ItemTree objects.

I want to convert this to string. When I make:

```
tree.ToString()
```

I only get:

```
        tree.ToString() "ItemTree"  string
```

But I want to convert the whole tree structure to string. How to do this?

Comment: you override ToString method.

Comment: well, what do you want it to look like? would json or xml suffice? or are you looking for something like at the top of the question?

Comment: @MarcGravell Json would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

You need to [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method in your class.

> When you create a custom class or struct, you should override the ToString method in order to provide information about your type to client code.

You can use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to serialize your object to XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can Override the [ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of  your class `ItemTree`

Or May be you can try with serializing with [json-net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `ToString` method and print your tree representation there

```
public class ItemTree
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return "Tree " + id +....
   }
}
```

otherwise you will always see class name as result of base ToString()

Answer (score 0):

If you override the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method, your implementation will be used by other code that calls ToString, simply because it's a standard method (inherited from Object).

Optionally you can implement a new method.

Either way, to avoid manually updating your method, you can generate a string using Json.Net like this:

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
```

Here is a sample [from the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm):

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

Nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/